# JavaFX Border and Label

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have no idea how to do this red line [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCVAr.png)

```
GridPane left = new GridPane();
            root.setLeft(left);
            left.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 15));
            Label l1=new Label("Panel plików");
            left.addRow(0,l1);
            left.setPrefSize(350, Double.MAX_VALUE); 
            Border b = new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)); 
            left.setBorder(b);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You want to put your label below the red border?

Comment: No, I want to put label "Panel plików" on the red border, just like in the picture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613716/set-title-in-border-of-vbox

Answer (score 1):

Use a stackpane, draw a rectangle on it, and then add another pane but this time anchor, so you can the layoutX and Y of the label, and also style the label with css (fx-background-color) giving the effect of the background. When done with the anchorpane, add another stackpane, this time, to implement your gridpane.

Comment: This was a brilliant solution!